# ActiveModel multi-step form not showing next step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, modal-dialog, activemodel

So I have been working on a multi-step form in ruby on rails (1.9.3) using Active model, following both the railscast #217 and #219 and am having problems with routing to the next steps in my form from /awizard/new to /awizard/1 hopefully someone can help me out. (I cannot use a form gem and must write this myself) I think this is a routing type issue (and I'm not using the id I give the model but I cannot figure out where I should be using it) a little help would be much appreciated!

**My controller code - (contollers/awizard_controller.rb)**

```
class AwizardController < ApplicationController

  def new
    # New Asset Wizard
    @wizard = Awizard.new(id: 1)
    # Set session variable as initial step
    session[:wizard_step] = @wizard.current_step
  end

  def update
    @wizard = Awizard.new(id: 1) unless !@wizard.nil?
    @wizard.current_step = session[:wizard_step] unless nil

    if @wizard.valid?
      if params[:back_button]
        @wizard.previous_step
      elsif @wizard.last_step?
        @wizard.save if @wizard.all_valid?
      else
        @wizard.next_step
      end
      session[:wizard_step] = @wizard.current_step
    end

    if @wizard.changed?
      render 'form'
    else
      @wizard.save
    end
  end

  def show
    render 'form'
  end

end
```

**My Model - (models/awizard.rb)**

```
class AWizard
include ActiveModel::Validations
include ActiveModel::Conversion
include ActiveModel::Dirty
include ActiveModel::Naming

#This class is used to manage the wizard steps using ActiveModel (not ActiveRecord)

attr_accessor :id
attr_writer :current_step  #used to write to current step
define_attribute_methods [:current_step] #used for marking change

def initialize(attributes = {})
   attributes.each do |name, value|
     send("#{name}=", value)
   end
end

def current_step
  @current_step || steps.first
end

def steps
  %w[step1 step2 step3] #make list of steps (partials)
end

def next_step
  current_step_will_change! #mark changed when moving stepped
  self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)+1] unless last_step?
end

def previous_step
  current_step_will_change! #mark changed when moving stepped
  self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)-1] unless first_step?
end

def first_step?
  current_step == steps.first
end

def last_step?
  current_step == steps.last
end

def all_valid?
  steps.all? do |step|
    self.current_step = step
    valid?
  end
end

def step(val)
  current_step_will_change!
  self.current_step = steps[val]
end

def persisted?
  self.id == 1
end

def save
 #will do later
end

end
```

**My views -** 
**(/views/awizard/_form.html.erb)**

```
<%=  content_for :awizard_form do%>
  <%= form_for(@wizard) do |f| %>
    <%= render "#{@wizard.current_step}_step", :f => f %>
    <%= f.submit "Previous", :name => "back_button" unless @wizard.first_step? %>
    <%= f.submit "Continue", :name => "step" unless @wizard.last_step? %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**(/views/awizard/_step1.html.erb)**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Step1' %><br />
</div>
```

**(/views/awizard/_step2.html.erb)**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Step2' %><br />
</div>
```

**(/views/awizard/_step3.html.erb)**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Step3' %><br />
</div>
```

**Routes code**

```
resources :awizard
```

**Error Message**
The error message I get after clicking the first continue button is as so -
"Template is missing

Missing template awizard/form, application/form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "fakepath/app/views""

more in depth error log shown below -

Started PUT "/awizard/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-07 10:12:06 +1300
Processing by AwizardController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"", "awizard"=>{"data"=>"data"}, "step"=>"Continue", "id"=>"1"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template awizard/form, application/form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "fakepath/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/awizard_controller.rb:40:in `update'

Rendered fakepath/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.6ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states , that there is no partial with the name `form` in the `awizard` directory. You should stick to the Rails convention about partials - a partial file is always prefixed by underscore .

In your case try to rename `form.html.erb` to `_form.html.erb` .

EDIT : You can try to render your partial like this

```
render :partial => 'awizard/form'
```

Comment: Hi Qumara i am sure i have already tried this but next chance i get i will try again

Comment: I have tried this and no this does not fix the problem I have a feeling that it is something to do with the routes?

Comment: When I look at your routes carefully , I see a duplication : if you have `resources :awizard` , it includes all the ingredients for proper operation . Try to comment  out this `post 'awizard/new' => 'awizard#new'` and post the result .

Comment: One more suggestion : try to copy the `form.html.erb` from `app/views/awizard/` to `app/views/` . It seems in your error log , the search is in the `views` dir. But I am absolutely sure , that the naming of partials should be with `_` in front of the name .

Comment: You are correct about the post 'awizard/new' => 'awizard#new' I have changed this but still the same problem I have the feeling it has something to do with the ID of 1 currently I have _form.html.erb  in /views/awizard I will try bring it back one into app/views but I do not believe this will fix it.

Comment: According to error log you've posted here , it is a plain partial missing . If there is another error , let's see it .

Comment: That is the error I got and have posted a more in depth error from the console above. but considering the _form.html.erb file is in the correct location I believe that this may not be the actual cause of the error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22282/discussion-between-learningdev-and-qumara-sixonetour)